# Why margin collapsing is not happening in this case?

Tags: css, margin

Why margin collapsing is not happening in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yR4hS/) case?

```
<p> First </p>
<p id="second"> Second </p>

p {
    background-color:red;
    margin-top:10px;
    display:inline;
    margin-right:10px;
}
#second {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

​The marging between those two ends up being 20px, instead of 10px. Why?
​

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [the doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> Horizontal margins never collapse.

Comment: ...unless you're in old versions of IE, but the fact that IE breaks the rules is not really a surprise.

Answer (score 0):

Margin collapses occur only between 2 vertical block elements.

You got horizontal elements and both of these are inline element. 

So, margin collapse is not occuring.

Answer (score 0):

You can always put the style in the HTML for secure work..?
Else use the Reset CSS aswell?